# Event system triggering on Translation manager job start / completed

Tags: 2013, event-system, translation-manager

I have found no event in Tridion core events that would trigger on Translation manager job start / completed. This somewhat makes sense as translation manager is not part of the Tridion core.

Do new events become available with installation of Translation manager, and if they do, is it possible to provide some examples or direct me where I can find out more about this.

If they don't is it possible to somehow trigger event system on translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the start of a translation job from the SDL Tridion events system, but I do not believe you can trigger an event upon the start or end of a translation job.

More details on the possible Translation Manager customization's are available [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_TranslationManager_20_SP2/concept_0A8B0913D1A741F6ADB74FBC83039BF0) [login required]

You can create a Translation Manager Plugin, which can execute at several points in the translation process, possibly allowing you to achieve your desired functionality. Here is a link to introduce [Translation Manager plugins](http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/translation-manager-plugins)

As for translation job completed, you could hook into the Component localized event (which happens following translation) and perform programmatic checks to determine whether the localization is human or Translation Manager initiated.